# Use git rebase after working on local branch

Tags: git

I am very new to git, and i think I have understood the basics so far, but I am not sure about some standard workflow.

So if I have a common situation, I did my last pull from a remote repository like

```
git pull master
```

days before, created a branch on it,

```
git branch myBranch
checkout myBranch
```

and worked several days on that branch.

Now, I want to push my branch with the changes onto the remote git repository, but of course first want to be up-to-date with the changes, that happened in the days between my last pull and now. How do I do it? I thought I should do

```
git rebase master
```

but however I have found some information that rebase should be avoided when possible.

So I am wondering what is the standard procedure in a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase is a good practice to get into when you are dealing with branches that will end up as pull requests. It makes the commit history cleaner and can help to avoid some merge conflicts.

The "old way" without `rebase` is to use `merge` onto your local branch.

```
master *---*-----------*---*
        \                   \ (merge)
myBranch *---*---*---*---*---*---*---*
```

This can clutter up your branch if you are merging `master` in many times prior to creating a pull request that gets your branch back onto `master`. Instead, a `rebase` here clips your branch start point and moves it up:

```
master *---*---*---*
     (rebase)...    \
myBranch             *---*---*---*---*---*---*
```

Anyone else that has been working on your branch on their own local copy will have a little difficulty when you `rebase`, but because your branch is only local to your machine, there is no worry of that.

You can perform a rebase with the commands:

```
(myBranch):$ git fetch
(myBranch):$ git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: ok, thank you a lot for the visualization, that is quite helpful. This is maybe a beginners question, but why is there a `git fetch` necessary before the rebase?

Comment: The `git fetch` updates your local refs to match the remote refs. This doesn't move your local `master` forward, but will move your local system's understanding of `origin/master` forward.

Comment: thanks a lot, I hope it will be clearer in future :)

Comment: but one more question, you said the fetch does not move my local `master`. Do I need to to this additionally - or is this exactly done by the rebase?

Comment: Your local `master` will stay in place until you `git pull` on it to move it forward. As long as you specify `origin/master` as your rebase target, you do not need to move it. If you used `git rebase master`, you should pull the `master` forward first.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "standard" procedure.

Some people prefer to merge master into the branch:

```
git checkout myBranch
git fetch
git merge origin/master
# adds a merge commit that merges currentmost master into myBranch
```

while others would rather rebase the branch on top of master (to have flat history):

```
git checkout myBranch
git fetch
git rebase origin/master  
# rewrites whole myBranch to start at currentmost master, instead of previous master
```

This is mostly about personal preference, particular project policy & tradeoffs of keeping the git history readable.

Answer (score 0):

When working on your `feature-branch` but at the same time the `master/develop-branch` went ahead. You need to update your `feature-branch`. To do so, you need to use a rebase so that your commits becomes the last ones in you `feature-branch`. You shouln't use a merge to update your `feature-branch` That will only complicate your git history.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git rebase master
$ git push origin mybranch
```